# Create Value Box in renderUI by Looping

Tags: r, shiny, lapply, shinydashboard

i want to create a value box according to the data i have.
suppose if i have 5 data variable `consumerdata` like this,

```
    id     data    number1   number2
1   k4j       A         67        53
2   rls       B         30        62
3   yv9       C         45        28
4   l6h       D         63        47
5   f08       E         96        75
```

then i need to create 5 value box with 'name' and 'number1' column.
I am getting No data displayed and no error.

## Code

```
ui <-  dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Consumer", tabName = "consumerdata")
    )
  ),  
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "consumerdata",
              fluidRow(
                tabBox(width = 12,
                       tabPanel("Label",
                                box(width = 12,
                                    uiOutput("consumer")
                                )
                             )
                          ) 
                       )
                    )
                  )
                )
             )

server <- function(input,output) {
  
    output$consumer <- renderUI({


  lapply(consumerdata$name, function(i) { 
    
    valueBox(i,
             consumerdata$number1,     #here display number1 one by one like name 
             width = 4
             )
      }) 
    
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is it always the fixed set of value boxes? Or I mean, Why are you using looping for it?

Comment: no the value box changes along with data....then how do i create value boxes and display the values inside it?..

Comment: so if you 10 rows then you want to show 10 value boxes? this is all dynamically which means, you don't know in prior that you need 10 right?

Comment: You can write your answer in the answer section!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i have gone some far...i have edited the code please have a look...now everything is working fine i am getting the name displayed, but how do i display 'number1' one by one in valuebox like name..

Comment: Could be please let me know what do you mean by one by one?

Comment: like i am displaying those 5 names from 'name' column in 5 valuebox according to the data ,i want to do the same for 'number1' an display those 5 numbers in that valuebox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got there, now you can iterate through a sequence of numbers instead of the elements itself and then use those numbers as index.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <-  dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Consumer", tabName = "consumerdata")
    )
  ),  

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "consumerdata",
              fluidRow(
                tabBox(width = 12,
                       tabPanel("Label",
                                box(width = 12,
                                    uiOutput("consumer")
                                )
                       )
                ) 
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output) {

  output$consumer <- renderUI({

    consumerdata <- head(mtcars) #comment this if you already have consumerdata defined

    consumerdata$name <- rownames(consumerdata) #comment this if you already have consumerdata defined

    consumerdata$number1 <- 1:6 #comment this if you already have consumerdata defined


    lapply(1:length(consumerdata$name), function(i) { 


      valueBox(consumerdata$name[i],
               consumerdata$number1[i],     #here display number1 one by one like name 
               width = 4
      )
    } )

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked...appreciate you guidance and help.